# Magento2 - After upgrade 2.2.4 to 2.3.4 facing issue with url key

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, url-key

In Magento2.3.4, I upgrade magento2.2.4 to 2.3.4 facing issue with category url key showing blank in category edit page in admin. Please check screenshot [image: Url key value showing blank, but in database value exist]

Answer (score 0):

In the **eav_entity_attribute** table, you should check whether the **attribute** **url_key** is assigned to the **attribute** **set** or not.

Comment: url key is not found